# How to use Adobe Analytics API 2.0 inside of a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, api, oauth, jupyter-notebook, adobe-analytics

I would like to call Adobe Analytics API 2.0 from inside my Jupyther Notebook. I do not need any "permanent" authentication between a server and adobe (or similar), I just want to get some (large amount of) data for analysis.

I already created an API key integration as described here (https://www.adobe.io/authentication/auth-methods.html#!AdobeDocs/adobeio-auth/master/AuthenticationOverview/APIKeyIntegration.md)

If I send an example call, lets say:

```
r = requests.get("https://analytics.adobe.io/api/myID/dimensions?rsid=myreportsuite&locale=en_US&segmentable=true&reportable=true&classifiable=false")
```

Obviously, I get the following answer:

```
'{"error_code":"403010","message":"Oauth token is missing."}\n'
```

How can I include my Oauth token in my request?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put them in `headers`, specifically by supplying a dictionary to the `headers` parameter of the `get` function as documented [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'

my_api_key = 'thisismyapikey9393'
my_product_name = 'my_app_0.1'

headers = {
    'x-api-key' : my_api_key,
    'x-product' : my_product_name
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I took the header name from `Step 3: Try It` in your adobe link.

> curl
>   'https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?locale=en_US%26search_parameters%5Bwords%5D=kittens
>   '   -H 'x-api-key:myAPIKey'   -H 'x-product:myTestApp1.0'

Comment: thank you for the answer! unfortunately its not working. If I implement it your way, I get "Oauth token is missing." If I add 'Authorization': <my_client_secret> to my payload, it says "Oauth token is not valid" . I double-checked the spelling, its definitely not a type.

Comment: have you implemented / tested OAuth using [this example ?](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/adobeio-auth/tree/master/OAuth/samples/adobe-auth-python)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a library that already deals with stuff like authentication for you. I came around [`python-adobe-analytics-2.0`](https://github.com/webhue/python-adobe-analytics-2.0) but have not used it myself. Probably, it is worth checking out even if just for looking at the code and adapting it to your needs. You can find some more info and documentation on that package on [this website](https://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-analytics-api-2-0/adobe-analytics-api-2-0-introduction/). (unfortunately the github repo is not really informative)

If you don't want to use this package, there is also a tutorial on the website on using JSON Web-Token (JWT) authentication with Adobe 2.0. Find it [here](https://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-io-user-management/adobe-io-jwt-authentication-with-python/).

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with this and created a package to be able to build requests that include multiple dimensions/metrics. More details at: https://analyticsmayhem.com/adobe-analytics/reports-v2-api-python/

In order to make the requests however you would still need to create a service account to authenticate (https://www.adobe.io/authentication/auth-methods.html#!AdobeDocs/adobeio-auth/master/JWT/JWT.md).

Let me know for any comments/feedback on the package.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, as they are rendered useless if the link stops working or the content significantly changes. You should [edit] your answer to include the most important information that's relevant to the question in the answer itself. Answers that are little more than links to external sites may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).